# how to uninstall Dictionary and other built in APPs?

Tags: applications, macos

I have a Macbook Pro. I want to uninstall built in apps, like Dictionary. How is this done?

Version 12.4 M1 chip

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: Version 12.4 M1 chip

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Since Big Sur, the OS is mounted on a cryptographically sealed, read-only volume. The OS won't boot if it has been 'tampered with'.

The Dictionary app is less than 15 Mb (most bundled apps are quite small - even Safari is only 14 Mb!), so there won't be a significant saving of disk space.